# How "SVN UP --set-depth infinity" with just folders/no files

Tags: macos, apache, svn, terminal

What I'm trying to do is check out a directory and all of its sub-folders without the files in them -OR- svn up a directory but only get the folders and not the files within them

Right now what I'm doing in OSX terminal is:

```
svn up --set-depth infinity
```

But this pulls all of the sub directories along with the files within them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't update in one command any of two needed forms.

`--depth` option accept only limited predefined set of arguments, none of which fit your needs:

- files updates only files in parent-dir
- immediates update both types of direct child - files and directories